# Free desktop client for Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, desktop-application

Which is the best <del>Open Source</del> free client for querying an Oracle database? 
It may additionally support other databases (MySQL, Postgres etc), since our development environment often requires switching between different databases.

Comment: Do you really need the source code to be open, or would just a free application suit your needs ? Besides, what platform will you want to run it on : Windows, Linux, MacOS ?...

Comment: A free application would be fine, I don't intend to do anything with the source. Platform would be Windows.

Comment: Good question, maybe change your question header to match the body?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I have been using the Oracle SQL Developer (because it's free) and at first hated every minute spent with it. I am still having weird problems with graphics, as it's running on Vista and there seems to be some sort of graphics driver problem (luckily, no-one can get it to run properly on Vista, so I am not alone in this), which makes its use quite cumbersome.

Nevertheless I had to learn how to cope with it and now I must admit it's a neat and very useful tool (NOT ONLY) for querying an Oracle database. I suppose you could query other DBs from it as well, for instance I have used it to query some legacy MS Access DBs, and so I believe you could query SQL Server as well.

You can do data migrations, imports/exports, see OWA output, and allegedly also DEBUG (step through, set breakpoints, etc...) PL/SQL code, but I haven't tried this. I have been fine with sqlplus command-line so far :) Do give it a try, and don't let the Vista-related graphics problems give you a wrong impression :)

Comment: For the visual glitching issues, the use of a JDK that is NOT included with SQL Developer seemed to resolve the problem.

Comment: I will certainly try that! I am really tired of that, although I found my ways around the problems, it just sometimes drives me crazy. Thanks for the advice

Comment: Just as a note I believe that the Vista Issues are with Java and not Oracle Sql Developer.  Something about how Java re-draws the form.

Comment: Well, very much depends on what angle you are looking at it from. Java redraws it all fine on an XP but not on Vista. You're quite right, could be problem on the Java side of it, but to me it looked like Vista-related (having seen it working on XP correctly).

Comment: You could try disabling direct draw in your Java run time options

-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true

(more info at http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/2d/flags.html)

Answer (score 8):

SQLTools is free and clean light weight client.
[www.sqltools.net](http://www.sqltools.net)

Comment: Connects to Oracle without configuration of thin client and everything (unlike Squirrel nightmare)   Toad and PL/SQL developer are the best COTS tools for Oracle, but for free,  SQLTools "works"   Thanks

Answer (score 7):

If by open-source you really mean free, then [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html) is free.  However it is not open-source.  It is fully supported though, we use it where I work all the time.

If you're interested you can go [here](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/files/what_is_sqldev.html) for a good starting reference on its features.

Answer (score 4):

What kind of "client" do you mean? Do you mean the actual drivers, or just an application you can get SQL results from? eg, [SQuirrel SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I jumped through hoops getting squirrel working at last company contract... but I got it working.  I added the thin oracle client but Unlike Toad and PL/SQL Dev. (paid tools / trials)  I'm having trouble with sockets etc... Below I see the  SQLTools is free and clean light weight client. www.sqltools.net  ... Tried it and works with no problems.

Answer (score 2):

Well Oracle provide SQL Developer for free, which is basically an Oracle IDE - lets you browse tables, code editor for PLSQL, SQL query window etc ...

Answer (score 0):

If you use a mac, You can try [macsequel - a native mac client for oracle](http://www.macsequel.com).

Answer (score -4):

One answer (for any platform and database) is just use ODBC.  E.g. on POSIX, [unixODBC](http://www.unixodbc.org/).  Oracle of course supports the standard with [their own drivers](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/windows/odbc/index.html).

Comment: In case you don't realize why you're downvoted: those are not desktop clients.